# How to use global const int variables from main class in another class

Tags: c++, sdl

**Situation:** I am trying to use figures stored in variables declared in the main class however I am required to use them in another class. I've tried putting the const int variables in a .h file and #include in the main class and the other class however this error which comes in the values.h file:

```
error C2370: 'LEVEL_HEIGHT' : redefiniton; different storage class
```

.h file:

```
 int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
 int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
 int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

//The frame rate
 int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 20;

//The dot dimensions
 int PLAYER_WIDTH = 20;
 int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 20;

//The dimensions of the level
const int LEVEL_WIDTH = 1280;
const int LEVEL_HEIGHT = 960;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "SDL.h" 
#include "Player.h"
#include "Values.h"
#include "LoadImage.h"



//The surfaces
SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

//The event structure
SDL_Event event;

Player player;
LoadImage game;


//The camera
SDL_Rect camera = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };


bool init()
{
    /****************/
    /*Initialisation*/
    /****************/

    //Start SDL 
    if(SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Set up Screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,SCREEN_BPP,SDL_SWSURFACE);

    if ( screen == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Set up window caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("10 seconds", NULL);
    return true;
}

void mainLoop()
{
    bool quit = false;
    //While the user hasnt quit
    while (quit == false)
    {



        //Move the player
        player.move();

        //Set the camera
        player.setCamera();

        //Show the background
        game.apply_surface(0,0,background, screen, &camera);
        //Show the player on the screen
        player.draw();


        //Update screen
        SDL_Flip(screen);
        /*if (SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
        {
            return 1;
        }*/


    }
}

void clean_up()
{
//      SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    player.clean();


        //Quit SDL 
        SDL_Quit();

}

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{ 
    //Initialise SDL
    if (init() == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //player = new Player("player.png", screen);

    //main loop
    mainLoop();

    clean_up();
    return 0; 
}
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Values.h"


using namespace std;

void Player::move()
{
    //Move the player left or right
    x += xVel;

    //if the player went too far to the left or right
    if ((x < 0)||(x + PLAYER_WIDTH > LEVEL_WIDTH))
    {
        //move back
        x -= xVel;

    }

    //Move player up or down
    y += yVel;

    //if the player went too far up or down
    if ((y < 0)||(y + PLAYER_HEIGHT > LEVEL_HEIGHT)) 
    {
        //move back
        y -= yVel;
    }

}

void Player::setCamera()
{
    //Center the camera over the player
    camera.x = (x + PLAYER_WIDTH / 2) - SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    camera.y = (y + PLAYER_HEIGHT / 2) - SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

    //Keep the camera in bounds
    if (camera.x < 0)
    {
        camera.x = 0;
    }
    if (camera.y < 0)
    {
        camera.y = 0;
    }
    if (camera.x > LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w)
    {
        camera.x = LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w;
    }
    if (camera.y > LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h)
    {
        camera.y = LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h;
    }

}

void Player::draw()
{
    //Show the player
    image.apply_surface(x - camera.x, y - camera.y, player, screen);
}

void Player::clean()
{
    image.clean();
}
```

Comment: You have another `LEVEL_HEIGHT` defined somewhere which is not const? Don't define those variables in .h file as they are not const.

Comment: Please show `Player.h` file.

Comment: Fixed it, I just forgot to add Const to the other variables (screen width, fps etc) within the values.h file

Comment: Why using const for something like that?
If you are using c++ just use:

#define LEVEL_HEIGHT 960

Comment: @TomF Whoa! Be careful there.

Comment: @TimOgunmakin other than that, you need to implement include guards in your header file.

Comment: @Nemanja Boric Be careful of what? what makes const int good practice in your view?

Comment: @TomF For example, it it scoped and type-safe way to define a constant. Here's quick list: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-vs-define.html

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Thank you for your answer, but i don't need to protect my code from myself. If the only reason for you to use const int instead of #define value is basically to limit the freedom of the programmer then no thank you, i'm sticking with preprocessor.

Comment: @TomF, OK, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You shoul start your headers with `#pragma once`. This prevents your header to be included several times. Also, do not hesitate to use forward declarations to speed up compilation time when you work on bigger projects.